# How should I remove these <li> elements based on time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 `<li>` elements on page load.

Other `<li>` elements are added randomly at every number of seconds. I need to remove the `<li>` elements that have been on the page longer than a minute.

I was thinking of having an attribute called `data-created-at` which stores the time it was added. And then have a looped function (via js, in the same page) that checks for `<li>` elements to be removed.

If above is a sound approach. Should I store the time for `data-created-at` in milliseconds?

Good idea? Or is there a better way to go about this? +1 for anyone who gives a code snippet along with their description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a better alternative, but couldn't you just use `setTimeout` to setup a planned destruction of the elements a minute after you create them?

There was a request to elaborate, so I'll do the best I can. This is going to be somewhat psuedocodey.

```
new_guy = $("<li>Some wonderful text</li>");
insert(new_guy);
setTimeout(function() { delete(new_guy); }, 60000);
```

Where you have defined a function `insert`, and a function `delete`, where insert does the actual inserting of your new `<li>` into your HTML, and `delete` is called after 60 seconds.

Comment: +1 for an alternative, good idea. (+1 pending more votes in 45 minutes ;)

Comment: @Sharth could you expand a bit more on your suggestion? Still trying to wrap my head around this

Answer (score 1):

The above is a good approach, especially using a timestamp that matches the local time on the computer in the attribute. (Don't have the server add the attribute, have JavaScript do it so that it is comparable.)

Your "looped" function should be something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var staleTime = (new Date).getTime() - 60*1000;
  $('li[data-created-at]').find(function(){
    return $(this).data('created-at')*1 < staleTime;
  }).detach();
},1000); // check every 1 second
```

Comment: Hmm, just a thought. If I set the time based on the computer. Won't it set the same time for any other new `<li>` elements? Since setting the time is based on the current DOM? i.e. `var time_now = new Date()*1;`

Comment: Each time you create a new li you create a new Date timestamp to go along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, jQuery's `.data` doesn't use `data-` attributes when setting, but I'd do it exactly as you describe:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if(new Date().getTime() - $this.data('created-at') >= 60000) {
            // It's been a minute
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

And, of course, if you have an existing `setInterval`/`setTimeout` loop, put that in there instead.